# Difference in Difference and clustering errors

Tags: stata, difference-in-difference, clustered-standard-errors

I have audience data for weekly TV news broadcasts from 50 different regions. So each broadcast (around 250 in total) has 50 different audience figures. My data contains two years (year1 and year2). In year1 I have 120 broadcasts x 50 regions. In year2 I have 130 broadcasts x 50 regions. Since each broadcast has different characteristics (e.g., like share of sports coverage, weather forecasts, traffic reports, political commentary, expert opinions etc), I don't want to aggregate my data at regional level. Instead I stay at broadcast level and take advantage of the fact that my data includes also broadcast specific variables. In year2 10 of the regions implemented a policy which I want to test in a simple DiD design (2x2).

My model looks like this:

TVAud = post + treated_region + post X treated_region + broadcast specific variables (day, content etc.) + Region FE

- Since the same broadcast appears 50 times, should I better cluster my
  errors at broadcast level or at region level?
- Moreover, I currently run an xtreg model. Are there any other suggestions?

Comment: Is treatment assigned at the broadcast level? Or at the region level?

Comment: The treatment is assigned at the region level. That is, some regions are treated and others not. The same broadcast is available in both treated and untreated regions.

Answer (score 1):

Typically one clusters SEs at the level at which treatment is assigned, which would be region for you. More on that [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/554287/7071).

You might also consider using `areg` if you have all the regions in your data (say if regions here are US states), but still clustering within regions.