# Instrument fails when I cluster standard errors

Tags: econometrics, instrumental-variables, clustered-standard-errors

I am replicating the Bhalotra-Figueras paper on women's political agency and health ([Paper Here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/43189382.pdf?casa_token=z-9aV91gw78AAAAA:fPeO9c5PuRPNeQyIAroW2gjydUE6Peyne7VrYsFz6_q3oZl0MS1PhSM7jxEtlpGLwJ658OLmK1KVZJ1dN3ZEW-vDva_lwXQ7PTcgg1ToOZdRfjWOeJ8)) an IV model where $x$ is measured at the district-level and have an instrument $z$ measured at the smaller constituency level. They use the mean of $z$ at the district-level as an IV for their endogenous $x$. They cluster their standard errors at the district-level given that the regressor of interest, women a district-level measure of female politicians, is entered as a district-level share.

My question is, given that the instrument voter turnout and margin of victory is measured at the smaller constituency level, shouldn't they cluster it at that point? When I try to do that with their data, their f-stat is very low and the Instrument fails (they do not report which f-statistic they are using - Cragg Donaldson or Kleibergen Paap). The instrument also fails when I cluster their standard errors at the state-level. At this point I should say that while the f-stat is miniscule they have some modicum of significance, but this should not be this falible for a top published article.

Can anyone help me understand why they should have clustered their standard errors as they did at the district level as opposed to where the instrument is measured or even higher at the state-level?

I have also consulted the Athey, Abadie, Imbens and wooldridge paper ([Here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.02926)) but can't really seem to agree that the SE clustering should not be at where the IV was measured.

Comment: Check out Section VII.B of the Cameron and Miller paper linked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/554287/7071).