# Alternative to Poisson regression if independence assumption invalid

Tags: regression, poisson-distribution, poisson-regression

does anyone know a suitable alternative to Poisson regression if the independence assumption is invalid? Thanks

A hypothetical example - if two cars crash into each other and they go to the same mechanic to get fixed. If the mechanic was modelling type of repairs and road conditions. Surely this makes the independence assumption invalid?

Comment: The answer is: it depends. Weighting,  quasipoisson, GLMMs, or GEE can all be used in different settings and with different inferences.

Comment: If you describe how the independence assumption is violated, that would help.

Comment: @AdamO  How could quasipoisson fix this?  (Maybe that word is used in multiple ways).

Comment: @PeterFlom Agresti covers this in Categorical Data Analysis 2nd Ed, Ch 5 (IIRC) on Horseshoe crabs. Basically, for Y_1, Y_2 \sim Poisson ( \lambda) where they are identically distributed, but correlated, you can rewrite the joint likelihood as L(Y_1, Y_2) = L(Y_1) L(Y_2|Y_1). Say Y_2 sim poisson(Y_1). But really Y_2 has unknown dependency structure. the sample mean is unbiased, the SE of the mean is sqrt of 1/2^2 ( var(Y_1) + var(Y_2)). But var(Y_2) = E(var(Y_2|Y_1)) + var(E(Y_2|Y_1) = E(Y_1) + var(Y_1) = 2 lambda. So the sample variance is overdispersed, and quasilikeihood corrects inference.

Comment: @AdamO Thanks for your input, but I thought quasipoisson would help with the mean = variance assumption being invalid , but not the independence assumption?

Comment: @jbowman A hypothetical example - if two cars crash into each other and they go to the same mechanic to get fixed. If the mechanic was modelling type of repairs and road conditions. Surely this makes the independence assumption invalid?

Comment: @Randomname - so it does!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go with your example, say you are modeling wheel alignments per mile driven. You have vehicle service data from a sample of auto mechanics, and you fit a Poisson model of alignments with miles as an offset and individual vehicle characteristics. You want to say something about expected alignments in the population of all driven cars.

Since people go to mechanics near where they live, work, or bought the car/tires, road quality will be an unobserved variable that creates positive correlations in the error terms between cars from the same area, which violates independence. If you have bad roads, you would expect more wheel alignments. You can probably make the same argument about income since alignments are a costly choice.

Three common solutions are

1. clustering standard errors at mechanic or geo-level (say a neighborhood or commuting zone)
2. include fixed effects for clusters from (1)
3. include measures of road quality from telemetry or structured data at cluster or even vehicle level
4. Aggregate data to the mechanic or cluster level, assuming data across mechanics is independent.

These are not mutually exclusive but slightly different. For example, (2) assumes that the effect is the same for all cars in the same cluster. That may be too strong. It will also pick up how good each shop is at scheduling rotations or upselling the alignments.

Clustering the errors can handle more subtle patterns that don't have to be the same: you could have stronger correlations between cars from near each shop but weaker ones for cars that commute in. If you have more ideas about the structure of the cluster, you can impose other assumptions (clustering by vehicle or tire type in addition to location).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do you have any resources that I can look at to see how this can be done please?

Comment: @Randomname Done as in code examples or textbook treatments with formulas?

Comment: I was thinking textbook, but both would be appreciated please

Comment: I would start with the newer papers/blogs [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/554287/7071), especially Cameron & Miller. For (4), maybe [Imbens and Rubin](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781139025751).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Randomname No need to thank me. You can select this as the answer by clicking on the checkmark.