# Is there another model for every model that has it's assumptions invalidated?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, poisson-distribution, poisson-regression

For example, I have a scenario where the independence assumption of Poisson regression is invalid. Is there a solution to this? Can I still use the model if I am interested in using it to look at the relationship between variables? Thanks

Maybe, I should have been more clear. Although, a models assumptions have been invalidated - can we still use it to describe the relationship between variables? As I know statistics is not always black and white

Comment: Can you explain how this is different from your other question? [Alternative to Poisson regression if independence assumption invalid](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/629538/alternative-to-poisson-regression-if-independence-assumption-invalid)

Comment: You might have accidentally asked a very profound question - is every model identifiable?

Comment: @Noah Please look at my edit please. Thank you.

Comment: @AdamO More so, is there a replacement model for every model that has been invalidated due to the assumptions being invalidated?

Answer (score 0):

In some sense, yes. Most models are part of a wider class of models. E.g. for a Poisson regression where some observations are not independent, there are models that can reflect correlations between observations.

Let's say we are modeling accident counts on different dates from different locations, when obviously some locations might just be more dangerous and some dates might just have more traffic/worse weather conditions etc., which we could reflect by having a random effect on the model intercept that varies by location as well as one that varies across dates (or you could make these fixed effects). However, this again comes with some assumptions that could be violated, too, for example one often assumes a normal distribution of random effects across units, but the distribution could be longer-tailed. Additionally, we might be able to explain some of the noise by having a fixed effect for weekday and public holidays, as well as reported dangerous road conditions for the particular location (because cold weather might be more of a problem is some locations than others, e.g. if these road locations are all over the US some day in mid-February will look very different in Hawaii, Alaska, Minnesota and Florida).

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this

Comment: Hi, I was just wondering what type of models you are referring to please? Thanks

Comment: E.g. random effects models (or just models with more model terms) that are commonly used to reflect that observations are correlated. So, in your Poisson example some kind of random effects Poisson regression such as can be fitted in R e.g. with `lme4::glmer` or ìf you want to do it in a Bayesian way e.g. `brms::brm()`.